# pandas - Fill missing values by looking up in other rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

---

## Name | Lastname | House ID

James | Potter | 12345

Harry | Potter | NaN

Anakin | Skywalker | NaN

Luke | Skywalker | NaN

---

I want to fill in the missing values in the House ID column by looking up the rows which have the same Lastname. But keeping in mind I can't do this for all rows like the Skywalker family above. So the result would be:

---

## Name | Lastname | House ID

James | Potter | 12345

Harry | Potter | 12345

Anakin | Skywalker | NaN

Luke | Skywalker | NaN

---

I got confused by indexing and keeping in mind the shapes and I couldn't write a descent function without using for loops which makes it very slow.

Comment: Surely there can  be multiple people with the same last name but different House IDs. How would you choose?

Comment: @Alexander It is trivially logical but let's just assume they don't in this dataset.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.fillna.html

Comment: does `df['House ID'] = df.groupby('Lastname')['House ID'].ffill()` work?

Comment: @anky_91 it will not in case of shuffled data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['James', 'Harry', 'Anakin', 'Luke'],
    'Lastname': ['Potter', 'Potter', 'Skywalker', 'Skywalker'],
    'House ID': ['12345', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
})
lookup_table = df[df['House ID'].notnull()][['Lastname', 'House ID']].drop_duplicates()
similar_addresses = (
    df[['Lastname', 'House ID']]
    .merge(lookup_table, how='left', on='Lastname', suffixes=['', '_same_last_name'])
    ['House ID_same_last_name']
)
df['House ID'] = df['House ID'].combine_first(similar_addresses)
>>> df
     Name   Lastname House ID
0   James     Potter    12345
1   Harry     Potter    12345
2  Anakin  Skywalker      NaN
3    Luke  Skywalker      NaN
```